# Dense subalgebra that is closed under unbounded derivation on noncommutative torus

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

Let $A_{\theta}$ be the noncommutative torus, we can define:
$$
A^{\infty}_{\theta}\mathrel{:=}\left\{\sum_{n,m\in\mathbb{Z}}a_{n,m}U^{n}V^{m} \,\middle\vert\, a_{n,m}\in S(\mathbb{Z}^{2})\right\}
$$
where $S(\mathbb{Z}^{2})$ is the space of rapidly decreasing sequences $a$, i.e. $\sup_{n,m\in\mathbb{Z}}(1+n^{2}+m^{2})^{k}\lVert a_{n,m}\rVert<\infty$ for any $k\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$. This is a dense subalgebra of $A_{\theta}$ which is closed under unbounded *-derivation $\delta$, i.e. $\delta(A^{\infty}_{\theta})\subseteq A^{\infty}_{\theta}$.

My question is, is $A^{\infty}_{\theta}$ the only dense subalgebra with the property that it is closed under unbounded *-derivation? In [Morita equivalence of smooth noncommutative tori](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0311502), Elliott and Li seem to imply $A^{\infty}_{\theta}$ is the only choice when talking about smooth structures on $A_{\theta}$. Does there exist another dense subalgebra which has the above property?

Comment: Please note that this smooth structure is canonical, because it’s exactly the dense $\ast$-subalgebra of smooth vectors for the canonical $\mathbb{T}^2$-action on $A_\theta$, which is given by $\alpha_{(t_1,t_2)}(U^m V^n) = e^{2\pi i (m t_1 + n t_2)}U^m V^n$. Again, [Bratteli–Elliott–Jorgensen](https://eudml.org/doc/152592) is the canonical reference for understanding $\ast$-derivations on irrational noncommutative tori.